# save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
import deepchem as dc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, glob

tasks, datasets, transformers = dc.molnet.load_hiv(featurizer='GraphConv')
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = datasets
print(datasets)

n_tasks = len(tasks)
model = dc.models.GraphConvModel(n_tasks, mode='classification')
hist = model.fit(train_dataset, nb_epoch=50)

metric = dc.metrics.Metric(dc.metrics.roc_auc_score)
print('Training set score:', model.evaluate(train_dataset, [metric], transformers))
print('Test set score:', model.evaluate(test_dataset, [metric], transformers))

model.save("HIV_test1.h5")
```

I want to save model, but it have error.

TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Read the documentation for `save`?

Comment: https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html

Comment: sorry. I am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for deepchem [`model.save()`](https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html#deepchem.models.Model.save) don't actually say much. But you can't provide a filename to it (it takes no additional arguments so implicitly, just the `model`).

It turns out that in order to "save", you need to [specify a `model_dir` when initialising your model](https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html#model). I haven't checked but *apparently* your model will be saved to that location after certain steps, like `.fit()`.

Using [this example](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/issues/1603#issuecomment-626354974) and applying to your code:

```py
# while creating
model = dc.models.GraphConvModel(n_tasks, mode='classification',
                                 model_dir='/home/user/HIV_test1')
                            # or model_dir=r'C:\Users\me\HIV_test1'
hist = model.fit(train_dataset, nb_epoch=50)
# etc.


# and later to load it:
model = dc.models.GraphConvModel(model_dir='/home/user/HIV_test1')
model.restore()
```

(Make sure that the `model_dir` you use points to the same dir consistently. Using just the filename means current dir where the script is being executed from so can vary. Also, that's supposed to be only a dir path and without a filename - the dir is used for checkpoints for that model. So then use separate dirs for separate models.)

Also, check out these related methods:

- [`Model.get_model_filename()`](https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html#deepchem.models.Model.get_model_filename)
- [`TorchModel.save_checkpoint()`](https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html#deepchem.models.TorchModel.save_checkpoint) (TorchModel)
- [`TorchModel.get_checkpoints()`](https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html#deepchem.models.TorchModel.get_checkpoints) (TorchModel)

Comment: I know this way, but it just saves the tensor weight instead of the model structure. I still haven't gotten an effective way to save the whole model.